# Pythonの再帰関数で戻り値がうまく return されない場合がある

Tags: python

下記のような関数を定義し、`a = func(1)`を実行すると`a`に`1`が代入されますが、その後`b = func(1)`を実行すると`list`は`[1, 2]`となりますが、`b`に値が代入されず`b`は`None`となってしまいます。

関数の中で再帰的に関数自身を呼び出した場合、うまく`return`されないのは何故でしょうか。また、`return`する方法はないでしょうか。

```
list = []

def func(x):
     if x in list:
         func(x + 1)
     else:
         list.append(x)
         return x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x in list` が成立したときに何も`return`していないため、`None` となっています。`return` してください。

```
    if x in list:
        return func(x + 1)
    ...
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました！

Comment: @user39541 解決した場合は、この回答に「承認済み」のマークを付けてくださいませ。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: 失礼いたしました。承認させて頂きました！